# Spurious double grant of "Steward" badge

Tags: bug, badges

I noticed that I have just been granted "Steward" badges a second time:

[image]

I guess that is a bug that should be fixed.

**Edit:** for the record – this has been fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are being changed; you're getting one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a queue. See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1201991_360194) by Stack Exchange staff member @animuson:

> There's supposedly an announcement about review updates coming out today, if it hasn't been published somewhere yet. Seems the code is getting ahead of itself.

However, there seems to be a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1202005_360194):

> This is my bug, caused by a temporary issue with and old batch job running after a migration took place. I have a fix I can roll out in a few.

Comment: Weird, thanks. Then the old badges should be removed.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be a bug (see the update or Meta.SE itself).

Comment: But it's going to be 1 gold badge for every 1000 reviews? That will be a good change as it's a small incentive to keep reviewing.

Comment: @Colin'tHart correct.